# Maven - Add directory to classpath while executing tests

Tags: maven-2

The Junits I have in my project need to load property files from the classpath. How can I specify the directory of those property files so that Maven will set that in the classpath before running the tests?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use the [build-helper-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html) to specify additional test-resource directories as follows. Using the configuration below, the contents of the test-resources directory will be copied to the target/test-classes directory during the *generate-test-sources* phase:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.12</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>add-test-resource</id>
      <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>path/to/additional/test/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>**/folder-to-exclude/**</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </resource>
        </resources>
      </configuration>
    </execution> 
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: It doesn't matter functionally, but for orderliness, shouldn't the phase be generate-test-resources instead of generate-test-sources?

Comment: You seem to have a typo in the `phase` s/add-test-sources/add-test-resources/
It would still work otherwise, but just more semantically correct.

Answer (score 60):

You can also add new test resource folders.

```
<build>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
        </testResource>
        <testResource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/something_else</directory>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
</build>
```

The first path, `src/test/resources`, is the default. Assuming you still want the default path to be used, make sure it's included. (The `testResources` tag overwrites your defaults, so if you don't include the default path explicitly, it will stop being used.)

Comment: This worked for me. +1 for pointing out the need for the default.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Much simpler than the accepted `build-helper-maven-plugin` solution. For anyone else looking for a good way to do this, the `<build><testResources>...` construct can also be added to your maven profiles, e.g. in case you want to specify different resources for different environments (local/dev/test/prod).

Answer (score 28):

If you just want to put your property files someplace on disk and don't want to copy those property files to target/test-classes during the build, you can do it this way

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <additionalClasspathElements>
      <additionalClasspathElement>/add/this/to/path</additionalClasspathElement>
    </additionalClasspathElements>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, m2e does not pick up Surefire's configuration when running tests from Eclipse. Too bad because this is a bit simpler than build-helper-maven-plugin's add-test-resource goal.

Answer (score 8):

Why not just use `test/resources` and place your properties in the classpath from that point.  They'll only be there for the test phase.

Comment: One has only one such folder, but often more than one test environment.

Comment: If you have a multi-module maven project you may need a common test data, which will be available on a classpath in more than one modules.

Answer (score 5):

If you have multiple resource environment you can use maven profile and put your various resources according to the profile you are testing.

```
test/resources/uat
test/resources/prod
test/resources/dev
```

But usualy if you need that you are making integration test then you don't need the build-helper-maven-plugin.

Answer (score 3):

The `maven-resources-plugin` has a `copy-resources` goal that will allow you to copy resources.  For example:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>additional-resources</id>
        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
          <resources>
            <resource>
              <directory>${project.basedir}/conf</directory>
            </resource>
          </resources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

This will copy the contents of the `conf` folder in the base of your project to the `target/test-classes` folder (unless you modified project.build.testOutputDirectory) which will be added to the classpath during your unit tests.