# Include non Java files and resources files to test-jar using maven jar plugin

Tags: maven

I would like to include scripts files as part of packaging test files using maven. I ma using the below plugin configuration however config and jython files the files are not package in the test jar

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/config/*</include>
                            <include>**/jython/*</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

is there anyway to include the files which are not in src/test/java and src/test/resources in test-jar?

Answer (score 10):

Specify additional test resource folders using:

```
<build>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/config/*</include>
                <include>**/jython/*</include>
            </includes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
</build>
```

You should then find that no config is required for the maven-jar-plugin.

The build-helper-maven-plugin may also be used. See: [Maven - Add directory to classpath while executing tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324767/maven-add-directory-to-classpath-while-executing-tests)

Comment: Great answer. The only thing I'd like to add is: <directory> should be src/test/ (no leading /) instead of / which will scan the entire hard drive.