# How to add a file externally in maven pom.xml?

Tags: maven, build

Is there any tag name available to do this?

I tried using `include` tag in `pom.xml` for including a file in local. However, while building a jar it didn't work.

Comment: This question would be improved by showing an example of what did not work and what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a part of maven-jar-plugin, unless you mean additional jar, then you can add it using dependency.

Please look here: [Maven : add external resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26672221/maven-add-external-resources)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add dependency in your **pom.xml**.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

groupId defines .jar files group

version is the version number of the file.

You can find the maven repository that you need on this site:
http://mvnrepository.com/

The IDE is gonna start to generate your file after paste the maven dependency code in the pom.xml