# How to build a java app in Maven with resources outside of ".jar"

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I made a little java app that modifies an Android Studio project and executes "gradlew.bat" to build the .apk and move it to an "output" folder.

As you might expect this project has to be saved outside of the .jar (AFAIK I can't execute a Gradle build inside of it).

I converted it from a plain Idea project into a Maven project to automate my workflow a bit. But Maven packs my resources in the "res" folder inside the jar. It also builds in the "target" directory and I want it in an isolated folder.

I need Maven to build the .jar file with the source files in an isolated folder and, in the same folder, copy the resources to the file system instead of the .jar.

**Edit:** For clarification. I want the project to have a more standarized layout so I can push the project to Heroku. Heroku will compile and execute the .jar using its Maven configuration but will not pass the other files to the filesystem to be along the .jar and instead, pack the resources inside the .jar.

The result I want is:

Whenever I execute a Maven build, the "target" directory should have the .jar file and two resources (A folder with files and a .ini file) within the same directory. It is not possible to do that myself as Heroku works automatically.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26672221/maven-add-external-resources

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're trying to do, but what stops you from simply passing the directory of the project to your application at runtime (e.g. as a command line argument)?