# Can not load hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, hibernate

I was going through a hibernate tutorial and faced this problem. Here is my code

```
public class HibernateTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(args[0]);
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(1);
        user.setName("John Smith");
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = createSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    public static SessionFactory createSessionFactory() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
                configuration.getProperties()).build();
        return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    }
}
```

And here is the structure of my project.

[image]

But I'm getting an exception, saying

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:2095)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2076)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2056)
    at HibernateTest.createSessionFactory(HibernateTest.java:25)
    at HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Comment: Is the file in the classpath ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clear in the error that `hibernate.cfg.xml` file is not in CLASSPATH.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
```

To keep the file in CLASSPATH, either move it to the folder /src/main/resources (or) put the current location of the file in CLASSPATH.

Comment: It's clear about moving into resources, but how do I add another folder to classpath?

Comment: @Carmine Seems you are using Maven for build. Refer this post to add a directory to Maven classpath. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324767/maven-add-directory-to-classpath-while-executing-tests

Answer (score 2):

Move the file into `src/main/resources` where it will be copied into your classpath at build time

Answer (score 2):

`hibernate.cfg.xml` has to be on the classpath. Files like that are considered a resource, and should be put under `src/main/resources`, which is put in the `classes` folder by build tools.